# Windows authentication from a Java Spring application

Tags: java, authentication, spring-mvc, active-directory, spring-security

I'm deploying a java application built with spring on a windows network. The network uses Active Directory so the users login to their desktops with their active directory user names.

Now, I'm trying to add a feature so that when the user opens the browser to access this application (which is deployed on the same network) the application automagically picks up their username and authenticates them.

During my research I came across this blog post:  http://blog.springsource.org/2009/09/28/spring-security-kerberos/ However, I think this approach might not be required in my scenario since I'm deploying the application to the same windows network.

**Question**

What could be some ways to simply access the user token so that my web app can authenticate the users?

Comment: Have a google for SPNEGO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use [NtlmHttpFilter](http://jcifs.samba.org/).

You configure it as a filter in your web.xml, tell it where your domain controllers live, and it pretty much just works. Internet Explorer will provide credentials without you taking any action, Firefox (and I suppose Chrome) will prompt you for a login.